# List Item link using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I've created a Material UI `ListItem` menu as follows.
And when I click on the button, it updates the URL to `http://localhost:3000/createIdea`, but the page does not load via the router.

If you go into the browser URL window and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then the page does load.

`DrawerMenu.js` has the routing:

```
<Route exact path='/createIdea' component={() => <CreateIdea />} />
```

And `App.js` -> `drawerMenu.js*` -> `tiledata.js`:

```
<ListItem button component={Link} to="/createIdea">   
    <ListItemIcon>
      <WhatsHotIcon/>
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Create Idea"/>
</ListItem>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What does } /> mean? If nothing, please remove it because it is confusing. It's either an emoticon or an obscure piece of code, but it would be nice to know.

Comment: `<ListItem button component={Link} to="/createIdea">` needs some fixing, so make `component` a complete attribute with `component="{Link}"`. Maybe this helps.

Comment: There is a react-router tag you can consider to add :)

Comment: What you've done is actually fine. What do you mean by "page does not load"? Do you see any errors in the console or on the page? Have a look at this demo and let me know if it helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/lpwq74p30m

Comment: solved the problem, the routing had <BrowserRouter> tag (in the menu.js) wrapping which I removed, not sure why it was there (from a tutorial), but once removed, it worked fine.

Comment: @KevinNaicker I had exactly the same problem! I think you are right <BrowserRouter> should be remove and keep only <Switch> with routes tags helped

Answer (score 7):

You can try this. It worked for me.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<ListItem button component={Link} to="/createIdea">   
    <ListItemIcon>
      <WhatsHotIcon/>
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Create Idea"/>
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of react-router-dom 5.2.0; @material-ui/core 4.11.0;

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Foo = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <ListItem onClick={() => history.push('/createIdea')}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <WhatsHotIcon/>
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Create Idea"/>
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me after I was having TypeScript pain with other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
 <List disablePadding>
    <ListItem button component={Link} to="/">
      <ListItemText>Home</ListItemText>
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem button component={Link} to="/about">
      <ListItemText>About Me</ListItemText>
    </ListItem>
</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different version for current MUI:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<ListItem key="someKey" disablePadding>
    <ListItemButton component={Link} to="/index" >
        ....
    </ListItemButton>
</ListItem>
```

Assuming then you have a Router like so:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
      return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/index" element={<YourIndexComponent />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -3):

Does wrapping the `Link` component around the `ListItem` component able to solve the problem? Like so:

```
<Link to="/createIdea">
    <ListItem>   
        <ListItemIcon>
          <WhatsHotIcon/>
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Create Idea"/>
    </ListItem>
</Link>
```